# How to access the properties of an object of a property to an object

Tags: javascript

is there a way to access the properties of the newly added objects to the properties of an already existing Object. i.e. how can I access for example
the properties of Degrees in:

```
nodes["Node2"] = new Degrees(1, 2, "u"+3, 4, 5, 6, "b"+7);
```

I can access property `"Node2"` (and I can the rest with a `for` loop) but I don't know how to access the properties of `Degrees`.
full code below. Thanks

```
var nodes = new Object;
function Degrees (degree1, degree2, degree3, degree4, degree5, degree6, degree7) {
    this.sg1 = degree1;
    this.sg2 = degree2;
    this.sg3 = degree3;
    this.sg4 = degree4;
    this.sg5 = degree5;
    this.sg6 = degree6;
    this.sg7 = degree7;
}

nodes["Node1"] = new Degrees(1, 2, "h"+3, "l"+4, 5, 6, 7);
nodes["Node2"] = new Degrees(1, 2, "u"+3, 4, 5, 6, "b"+7);
nodes["Node3"] = new Degrees(1, "b"+2, "b"+3, 4, 5, "b"+6, "b"+7);
nodes["Node4"] = new Degrees(1, 2, 3, "h"+4, 5, 6, 7);
nodes["Node5"] = new Degrees(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, "b"+7);
nodes["Node6"] = new Degrees(1, 2, "b"+3, 4, 5, "b"+6, "b"+7);
nodes["Node7"] = new Degrees(1, 2, "b"+3, 4, "c"+5, "f"+6, "m"+7);
```

Comment: `nodes["Node2"].sg1`…?

Comment: What exactly is the use-case here? I'm assuming this is an over-simplified example - because there's *no* advantage that I can see to this `Degrees` constructor over just using an array `[degree1, degree2, degree3, degree4, degree5, degree6, degree7]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily access properties of degree using either of these ways

`console.log(nodes["Node2"]["sg1"]);`
or 
`console.log(nodes["Node2"].sg1);`
or
`console.log(nodes.Node2.sg1)`

The same way you can access properties of any entry in the array.

Comment: Thank you much appreciated.

Comment: If it works for you, you can mark it as the accepted answer and the question will me marked as solved. :-) welcome to stack overflow.

Comment: Or using all dot notation `console.log(nodes.Node2.sg1)`

Comment: Editing answer to add that as well.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness @LloydFrancis

Comment: People here are all helpful. :-) That's why we're here. To learn and help learning. No one's being kind, least of all me. But thank you. @TheOrchestrator